# yii - post fitler and redirect not returning the correct Controller / Action pair

Tags: php, yii, redirect, yii-filters

I have a filter that runs on all my controllers.. 
in `preFilter` I have:

```
protected function preFilter($filterChain){
        Yii::app()->params->controller = Yii::app()->controller->id;
        Yii::app()->params->action = Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
        return true;
    }
```

in the `postFilter` i have:

```
protected function postFilter($filterChain){
    $this->controllerName = Yii::app()->params->controller ;
    $this->actionName = Yii::app()->params->action;
    $this->CheckTrigger();
    return true;
}
```

The function `CheckTrigger()` refers to `Yii::app()->params->controller` and `Yii::app()->params->controller`.

So here is the issue.. If i have a redirect in my action this brakes. If i comment out my redirect it starts working again. It seems that when the redirect is called the Pre and Post Filter actions are also called but the Post filter is never called before the redirect is initiated.. Is there a way to ensure that the post filter is called before a redirect? Am i missing something here?

many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this redirect code in your controller action:

```
$this->redirect('url here', false);
```